# What is the purpose of setting a calculated column to be PERSISTED?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

My table with the `calcIncome` calculated column:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(100),
    [other columns], 
    calcIncome AS dbo.fn_calcIncome() PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

Query:

```
select * 
from foo
where calcIncome > 100
```

Even though I set `calcIncome` to be `PERSISTED`, this query still calls `fn_calcIncome` for every single row.

So what exactly is the purpose of setting a calculated column to be `PERSISTED` if it behaves the same as non-persisted calculated columns?

Comment: rows are processed row by row, so the function is called as well row by row, if the value is constant cross JOIN a select of that function, soit is called only once

Comment: You can use `option (querytraceon 176)`. See https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns

Comment: @nbk Right, but if the value is persisted to disk, why recalculate? The value is already available.

Comment: @MartinSmith This link was illuminating.  It appears that if I create an index on the persisted calculated index and then force usage of this index, it won't recalculate anything.  I think the price is too high.  Probably going with a trigger that just updates the column on insert/update is less expensive.

Comment: the sql server can't know that, so it tries to calculate it over and over again, try another approach or use martins suggestion

Comment: @nbk I must be missing a step.  Sql server does know that because I marked the column as PERSISTED.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Paul White's article [Properly Persisted Computed Columns](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns)

> Persisted computed columns were added to the product specifically to
> allow indexes to be built on deterministic but "imprecise" (floating
> point) columns

So preventing re-evaluation of calculations - including UDFs was not the design goal.

But the article does also mention that there is a trace flag 176 that can help in this respect.

In general with computed columns whether or not the column is marked as `persisted` in the data page you can index it and then can get an index seek using the value stored in the index. But I have just tested that and [wasn't able to get a seek](https://dbfiddle.uk/DJvDFG5H) when the index was built on the column referencing a UDF either (without both marking the column as `PERSISTED` and trace flag 176).

I rarely if ever use computed columns that reference scalar UDFs as they also have implications for parallelism.